# PowerShell search .csv file field for string format and remove exceptions

Tags: powershell

I have a problem where I have a column of data (codes) in a .csv file (can change format to .xlsx or anything else if needed) that is not all correct.  For example, a cell contains the following:

"E86   F03   R64   03  R 64    86  F     U "

And I would like to ONLY keep the entries that in the format <1 character><2-3 digit integer> and remove the other stuff.  Using the above example, I would like to update the cell to look like the following:

"E86   F03   R64"

My major issue is that I cannot seem to figure out how to search the file for a generic format like <1 character><2-3 digit integer>.  I would also be open to suggestions outside of PowerShell such as using an Excel formula.  Would anyone be able to assist me with such an issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
("E86 F03 R64 03 R 64 86 F U ".split() -match '^[a-z]\d{2,3}$') -join ' '
```

Comment: How about if I wanted to make it generic so that it could update thousands of fields in a file?

Comment: Something like: (Get-Content file.txt) | Foreach-Object{ ($_.split() -match '^[a-z]\d{2,3}$') -join ' '} | Out-File file.txt